# Error using REST API: "error_description": "AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID:

Tags: api, rest, postman, app-secret, azure-purview

I'm trying to use the REST APIs to delete Assets in Purview but I keep this error:
"error_description": "AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID:

I have an App Registration that is assigned both the Owner and Purview Data Curator of my Purview Account.

When I enter the values of the App Registration along with it's client secrets (screenshot 1) into Postman I get an invalid client error (screenshot 2)

**Screenshot 1**
[image]

**Screenshot 2**
[image]

**Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance?**

Comment: You don't use the secret ID, lol. You use the secret value, that thing that starts with `TPD...` and is hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed. It was the Secret Value.

Glad this was such a simple fix!

[image]